# Can I get (directly from gamecenter) a total (sum) of all scores uploaded to an apple gamecenter leaderboard

Tags: game-center-leaderboard

For a single gamecenter leaderboard I want to get a total of all scores uploaded within the last week.

Currently I query the leaderboard with a start of 0 and range of 100, fetch the scores, add those scores to a running total, fetch another 100 with a new start at 100, add those to the running total; keep doing this until gamecenter returns no scores.

This works but it is not efficient as the multiple fetches to the leaderboards takes quite a bit of time.  I am hoping there is a total stored somewhere on the gamecenter server that I can access directly.

The following is one call to gamecenter and totaling all of those scores

```
   NSInteger scorePercent = 0;

   localLeaderboard.range = NSMakeRange(rangestart, 100); 
   [localLeaderboard loadScoresWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSArray *scores, NSError *error) {
        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"leadboard loadScores returned error =  %@", error);
            // handle the error. if (scores != nil)
        }
        if (scores != nil){
            // process the score information..

            NSInteger numScores = localLeaderboard.maxRange; // number of leaderboard entries returned.
            for (NSInteger nscores=0; nscores < numScores; nscores++ ) {
                scorePercent += ((GKScore*) scores[nscores]).value;
            }
            scoreTotal += scorePercent // aggregate for later percentage calculations
        }
    }];
```

Current method works but is not efficient.

Comment: Did you figure this out?